# Why button not created properly in JS function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I create button dynamically in my JS function and the put created button to the DOM.

Here is the code:

```
      var button = '<button id="btnStrView" type="button" onclick=' + parent.ExecuteCommand(item.cmdIndex) + ' class="button_air-medium">'+
                   +'<img id="streetView" class="miniToolbarContant" src="../stdicons/streetview-icon.png">'
                   +'</button>'

        $( "#tdStrView" ).append(button);
```

When I display the creted dynamically button in consle I see this:

```
"<button id="btnStrView" type="button" onclick=undefined class="button_air-medium">NaN</button>"
```

it seems that but not created properly the onclick is undefined and img tag is missing.

any idea what I do wrong? Why image button not created properly?

**UPDATE:**

I tryed to add double quotes to the onclick event:

```
onclick="' + parent.ExecuteCommand(item.cmdIndex) + '"
```

and the created button is:

```
"<button id="btnStrView" type="button" onclick="undefined" class="button_air-medium">NaN</button>"
```

the onclick is still undefined.

Comment: Don't create the button through HTML text. Use `document.createElement('button')` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Comment: document.getElementById( "tdStrView").innerHTML=button;

Comment: I think problem is there: parent.ExecuteCommand(item.cmdIndex) please post full code to get the scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add double quotes.onclick will look like this `onclick ="yourFunction()"`

```
onclick="' + parent.ExecuteCommand(item.cmdIndex) + '"
```

Comment: I tryed please see updaet.

Answer (score 0):

```
// add double quotes in onClick and if you are getting NaN in place of image, 
// it means that it is trying to add numbers. I'm not sure yet why this is happening, but
// to fix that, add extra string in second line. like this. and then console button.

var button = '<button id="btnStrView" type="button" onClick="alert(7)" class="button_air-medium">'+
               +'' +'<img id="streetView" class="miniToolbarContant" src="../stdicons/streetview-icon.png">'
               +'</button>'
```

Comment: I believe your "item is a javascript variable". so it won't work in string.
You should create button, image using document.createElement as suggested in above comments. 
It would be more easier.

Answer (score 0):

While this code is a lot more verbose, it is more readable and less error prone.

```js
const button = document.createElement('button');
button.id = 'btnStrView';
button.type = 'button';
button.className = 'button_air-medium';
button.addEventListener('click', event => {
  parent.ExecuteCommand(item.cmdIndex);
});

const img = document.createElement('img');
img.id = 'streetView';
img.className = 'miniToolbarContant';
img.src = '../stdicons/streetview-icon.png';

button.appenChild(img);
$( "#tdStrView" ).append(button);
```